# Add, Adding Added to Bag onclick button states

Tags: jquery, css

I have a button element that I want to use as an 'add to bag' button but I would like to change the text for several states once the button has been clicked by the user. The buttons initial state will say "Add to Bag" then after the user has clicked the button the button should change to a spinner image then after a 1 second animation of this state the next state would go say "Added to Bag!" and then finally it would return back to the original "Add to Bag" state.

A working example of what I'm trying to achieve can be found here
https://milkmakeup.com/products/matcha-cleanser/

I have added the partial code I have that creates everything but the spinner state

```
// Cart button text change
(function() {
  $(".btn-cart").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      oldText = $this.text();

    $this.text("Added to Bag!");
    $this.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.text(oldText);
      $this.removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 1600);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Are you actually making an AJAX request when the button is clicked, or are you just faking it with a timer for this example?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it would just be a fake animation (for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY BELOW SAMPLE

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Cart button text change
  $(".btn-cart").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      oldText = $this.text(); 
 $this.html("<img width='50' height='50' src='http://www.bebestore.com.br/images/shared/lazyloader.gif'/>"); 
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.text("Added to Bag!");
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("img").hide();
      $this.show();    
      $this.text(oldText);
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```css
button,div{text-transform:uppercase;background: #828282;
    border: #828282 1px solid;
    color: #fff;    transition: opacity 0.2s;    border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Calibre SemiBold", arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    line-height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 170px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;}
/*div {
    border: 7px solid #f3f3f3; 
    border-top: 7px solid #3498db; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    
}*/
span {
    background: url(https://www.storefirst.com/static/common/images/loading-spinner.svg);
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-cart">Add to bag</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the spinner within the button, not replacing it? also, it doesn't have to be CSS spinner, it could be an image if that is more practical

Comment: @Dan Farrell now check it

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this quite smoothly by providing the original text in markup, then changing the text before and after the timeout

```
<button class="btn-cart">Add to bag</button>

$(".btn-cart").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text("Adding to bag");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.setText("Added to bag!");   
    }, 1000);
});
```

---

**Edit** in response to comment

> I kinda need it to display a spinner rather than say adding to bag

If you change your markup a little, this should also be quite easy

```
<button class="btn-cart">
    <span class="btn-cart--text">Add to cart</span>
    <span class="btn-cart--loading" style="display: none">
        <img src="spinner.gif" />
    </span>
</button>

$(".btn-cart").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $text = $(".btn-cart--text", $this);
    $loading = $(".btn-cart--loading", $this);

    // Hide text and show loading spinner
    $text.css("display", "none");
    $loading.css("display", "block");        

    setTimeout(function(){
        // Change text, show text, hide spinner
        $text.setText("Added to bag!");   
        $text.css("display: block");
        $loading.css("display", "none");
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: thank you!

I kinda need it to display a spinner rather than say adding to bag (like the example site) and it needs working timeouts to return back it's original state

Comment: it breaks after clicking? it doesn't return to its original state

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you require you can update the button on click by changing the text and appending a loading spinner image. You can then use a couple of timers to change the text in sequence after that. Something like this:

```js
$('.btn-cart').click(function() {
  var $btn = $(this).prop('disabled', true).addClass('adding').html('<img src="https://i.imgur.com/01yMDgZ.gif" />Adding to bag...');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $btn.text('Added to bag!').toggleClass('adding added');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $btn.text('Add to bag').removeClass('added').prop('disabled', false);
    }, 1000)
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
.btn-cart {
  background-color: #C00;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

.btn-cart.adding {
  padding-left: 35px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.btn-cart.added {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.btn-cart img {
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-cart">Add to bag</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! this works. Just some tweaks from my end on styles but the concept works how I needed perfectly